# USB-C to DisplayPort Adaper still not recognised in Linux kernel 4.19

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, display, displayport

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded to Linux kernel mainline 4.19.2 with ukuu, which purportedly supports DisplayPort alternate mode for USB-C.

```
alex@gta-65:~$ uname -a
Linux gta-65 4.19.2-041902-generic #201811132032 SMP Tue Nov 13 20:34:19 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Other USB-C devices work fine on this Lenovo X270. However alternate mode doesn't kick in when my generic dongle is inserted, which works fine with a colleague's Windows PC; no events are generated in kern.log & dmesg.

Is there something I need to look into further, or another display-related library I need to update to have this working?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest cause is usually the easiest - the confusing bundle of cables on this hot desk, once untangled, revealed that the DisplayPort cable was not plugged in.

Now, when connected, kern.log tells me:

```
Nov 19 14:36:02 GTA-65 kernel: [17099.717660] [drm] Reducing the compressed framebuffer size. This may lead to less power savings than a non-reduced-size. Try to increase stolen memory size if available in BIOS.
```

So Linux kernel 4.19 does support alternate mode for USB-C to Display Port